# Advanced "Careers Alerts" option - filter on "has posted salary" or "salary range = x"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I've started noticing today that the "Find Jobs Near You" widget sometimes has a posted salary range. Not sure if that is new, but either way, it is super useful (and maybe a little distracting)

I looked in to the https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/create-job-alert page and noticed that there are no options around the "has posted salary" or `"salary range includes value greater than ${value}"`

If I were to consider creating a stack-careers-job-alert for updates via email, while "passively not actually looking", a salary range filter would be the thing that made me notice a role.

Do you think you (the stack careers team) think you could add that filter to the job alerts?

I suspect that based on the 2016 developer survey https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#work-job-priorities ~62.7% of developers might be interested in seeing that filter as well.

Comment: I've marked this as status-completed because there's a workaround for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not exposed directly in UI right now but you can enter an [advanced search query](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search-jobs) to get alerts for these kinds of jobs.

For example, entering `salary:10000USD` in the keywords box would filter for all jobs with a salary of $10000 or more.

[image: Create Job Alert]

We're working on making the jobs search experience better, including making this kind of functionality more accessible in the coming weeks!

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks @dean-ward

Comment: I've just received a "We really like this job for you." e-mail and it seems to totally ignore my salary preferences. Is there a way to fix this?